# Why does getter return false even though the vuex store is updated with the created hook?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I save the id information to localstorage during authentication in my project. If the user refreshes the page and is logged in, I want him to stay on the current route, if he has not logged in, he will be directed to the login page. Actually I did everything right; but it must be an overlooked detail.

1)I call the initAuth action when the project is created in App.vue

```
 created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("initAuth");
  },
```

2. ```
   initAuth({ commit }) {
     let id = localStorage.getItem("id");
     let fullName = localStorage.getItem("fullName");
     if (id && fullName) {
       commit("updateUserInfo", { id, fullName });
     }
   },
   ```

3)Then the updateUserInfo mutation is running

```
updateUserInfo(state, payload) {
    state.id = payload.id;
    state.fullName = payload.fullName;
  },
```

4)And in getter I return a result based on state.id

```
     isLoggedIn(state) {
        return state.id !== "";
      },
```

5)Then I want to operate on the router according to this state; but even though id exists, isLoggedIn returns false !!

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);
console.log(store.getters.getUser);
console.log(store.getters.isLoggedIn);
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      if (store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
        next();
      } else {
        next("/giris-yap");
      }
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/giris-yap",
    name: "Login",
    component: Login,
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      if (store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
        next("/");
      } else {
        next();
      }
    },
  },....
```

[6)The outputs of console.logs are as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p34Wh.png)

Comment: This, perhaps? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 0):

I understood that routes were created before the created hook. Therefore, I gave setTimeout (..., 0) to the beforeEnter conditions. The problem has been fixed.